# Proved algorithm to Create Graph With Eulerian Tour?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, graph-algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I wonder if it exists a **proved algorithm** that given a set of nodes it creates a graph with eulerian tour. I've looked for it in google but i've just found the Fleury's algorithm, which only says if we can find an eulerian tour in a graph. Do you know if such an algorithm exists? Thanks :)

Comment: What properties should the created graph have? As you stated it, connecting all nodes with a single path will satisfy the existence of Eulerian tour.

Comment: There is an algorithm that given a weighted graph would double edges of minimal total weight in a way that the resulting graph is Eulerian. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @kajacx Exactly, that's one possibility. But there are more ways to obtain an eulerian tour. Do you know those algorithms?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I could be. What's the name of this algorithm? Where can I find the Python, C or Java implementation? Thanks

Comment: The problem is known as the Chinese Postman Problem or as known in wikipedia [Route inspection problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem)

Comment: @GniruT Maybe if you say *why* you need it, I might be able to help you more. You could add one path connecting all nodes and then add remaining edges randomly.

Comment: @kajacx i just want to know if there's an algorithm that given a set of nodes it can create a graph with eulerian tour. Connecting all nodes with a single path is just ONE possibility but does exists a theorem or algorithm that enumerates ALL possibilities to create  a graph with eulerian tour? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is an answer to the comment which adds more details to the question).

The problem "find all possible eulerian tours given a set of nodes" is the same as "find all eulerian tours in a complete undirected graph". This is an open problem with some approximation problems available.

Some details on research [here](https://www.era.lib.ed.ac.uk/handle/1842/4759) and [here](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~stefanko/Talks/EULER.pdf)